# Can anyone suggest a QR code scanning library for the ReactJs which can work in Chrome browser of IPAD?

Tags: reactjs, qr-code

I am looking for a QR code scanning library for the ReactJs project.

I have tried the following react libraries but all libraries have a common issue that they do not work in **Chrome browser of IPAD**.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-scanner

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-reader

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qrcode-scan

In the Safari browser, it is working all fine but cannot understand what issue occurs in the IPAD chrome browser.

If there is no such library available, can you suggest any way to scan QR code in IPAD chrome browser?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to search this library here

[https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=QR%20code&ranking=popularity](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=QR%20code)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at following react npm library called as [React QR Reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-reader)

It used webcam utility to read QR Code info. We have used this and its quite reliable.